# File not deleted using log4j2

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 version 2.19.0.

I want to delete the old files in Tomcat folder. But when I run my program, the files was not deleted.

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = LogToRollingFile

appender.rolling.fileName = /var/lib/tomcat/logs/logger.log
appender.rolling.filePattern =   /var/lib/tomcat/logs/logger.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.gz

appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = /var/lib/tomcat/logs/
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 2d

# Log to console and rolling file
logger.app.name = aHello
logger.app.level = info, error
logger.app.additivity = false
logger.app.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
```

I check the /var/log/ folder, and I saw the below error

```
2022-09-22 14:53:38,384 Log4j2-TF-1-RollingFileManager-1 ERROR Error in post-rollover Delete when visiting /var/lib/tomcat/logs java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/tomcat/logs: Read-only file system
```

Is there any other method I can use to delete the log file by using lo4j2 library?
Currently, I already include the *log4j api and core lib* to my code.

Thank you.

Comment: "Read-only file system" should be an indication of what is going wrong. Most modern Linux distribution run Tomcat through SystemD with the [`ProtectSystem=strict`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectSystem=) option on. Try replacing `/var/lib/tomcat/logs` with `/var/log/tomcat`.

Comment: My guess is that `/var/lib/tomcat/logs` (read-only) is a symlink to `/var/log/tomcat` (read-write).

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz
Thanks... Your suggestion works... Managed to delete those related file.

Answer (score 0):

As per mentioned in comment, answer works for changing the part to /var/log/tomcat